# integrate (RIM java)app with BB address book

Tags: blackberry, integration

I want that my api How to integrated RIM app with BlackBerry Address Book.For example:-**send an SMS message by selecting a contact from BB native address, pressing the menu button, and choosing option Compose SMS via XYZ app** like we have compose sms.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to create a class, extend `net.rim.blackberry.api.menuitem.ApplicationMenuItem` and override the `run(Object context)` method.

This method will be called when the user clicks your menu-item and the context object will be of type `javax.microedition.pim.Contact`, so you can get all the relevant address information of the highlighted item.

Override toString() method to give your MenuItem a name, e.g.

```
public String toString() {
    return "MyMenuItem";
}
```

Next you need to register you menu item. Create an auto-start, system-module application and call these methods:

```
        ApplicationMenuItemRepository.getInstance().addMenuItem(
            ApplicationMenuItemRepository.MENUITEM_ADDRESSBOOK_LIST, instanceOfYourApplicationMenuItem
        ); 
        ApplicationMenuItemRepository.getInstance().addMenuItem(
            ApplicationMenuItemRepository.MENUITEM_ADDRESSCARD_VIEW, instanceOfYourApplicationMenuItem
        );
```

The first call will register the menu item in the addressbook list view, the second one in the detail view (after an address has been opened).

Hope that helps!

Comment: hello Is it possible to add option in native address book Blackberry?.For eg. Suppose my BB java app name is XYZ now i want that this XYZ option would come in the Full menu of native address book of BB..Is it possible or not? Please reply soon..

Comment: yea sure just override toString() method